# MySQL QueryOptimizer seems to randomly use index (or not)

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I just found the following behaviour of MySQL using InnoDB engine. Is there a way to explain the significant difference in execution time?

First Query:

```
   SELECT ask FROM history_time  WHERE ask> 1.5790 AND timestamp BETWEEN 1207000800290 AND        1207690900290
```

Execution time: 0.715sec

```
   EXPLAIN: '1', 'SIMPLE', 'history_time', 'range', 'PRIMARY,timestamp,ask,ask_2', 'PRIMARY', '8', NULL, '3278190','Using where'
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT ask FROM history_time  WHERE ask> 1.5790 AND timestamp > 1207000800290
```

Execution time: 0.002sec

```
EXPLAIN: '1', 'SIMPLE', 'history_time', 'range', 'PRIMARY,timestamp,ask,ask_2', 'ask', '4', NULL, '5850604', 'Using where; Using index'
```

Third Query:

```
SELECT ask FROM history_time  WHERE ask> 1.5790 AND timestamp < 1207690900290
```

Execution time: 0.651sec

```
EXPLAIN: '1', 'SIMPLE', 'history_time', 'range', 'PRIMARY,timestamp,ask,ask_2', 'PRIMARY', '8', NULL, '3278190', 'Using where'
```

EXPLAIN tells me, that only the second query uses an Index. My table contains 83 Mio. rows, Primary Key is timestamp. I also have an index on (ask, timestamp) and one on ask (which is redundant and only there for testing purposes). Why is MySQL only using an index on the second query?

Comment: can you add explains for each query please, and please time your sql queries using `SQL_NO_CACHE` : `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ask FROM history_time  WHERE ask> 1.5790 AND timestamp > 1207000800290`

Comment: thanks, i just added the explains - timing is done without using cache

Answer (score 1):

Your answer lies in : [The Range Access Method for Multiple-Part Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-multi-part)

Edit :  And also you would better check this : [mysql range index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368020/mysql-range-index). there is a possibility that optimizer decides that it would be faster to use full scan then index.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: that depends on cardinality of "ask" column. if you would query for a specific time and your timed data is smaller than ask cardinality I would suggest an index on timestamp; if not it would be a waste on resources and space.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is specifically ranged by timestamp as the primary key, but also an index on Ask via your comment (ask, timestamp).  Swap it... you want the smaller granularity at the first position... (timestamp, ask)... unless you are asking for a very specific ask value, or range of ask values.  Think of it this way.

If you have 83 million rows and you are asking for something that happened within a timeframe of X and Y, the timestamp is your basis... why consider anything lower or greater than the range in question.  Now, you add on the "ask > someValue", the optimizer can get confused.  Guess.. are there less values that are greater than the ask value, or less values based on the timestamp range provided.  If you had an index on (timestamp,ask), it would be able to utilize it better.  Within the range provided, only give ask > SomeValue.

If the optimizer used the current Ask index, it is basically going through all entries that are greater than the value provided ... then within each one, jumping to those within the timestamp range.

Now, swap your criteria.  If you were looking for a specific "ask" value or range, then your current index would be perfectly fine.  It would focus on that range only.

Comment: How will a `(timestamp, ask)` index help? The query is using range conditions on both columns.

Comment: @ypercube, I guess I was looking at the first entry with a between basis, but the wide-open "lose" criteria, without knowing more stats on "ask" range values" or what they are trying to actually attain in results is tough.  Using timestamp first position though, and a between, if would be able to optimize the specific range first, then only grab those entries greater than the "ask" value vs all "ask" values that may be from years old to current.  Tough call otherwise.